# How to write an SQL query comparing between two dates?

Tags: python, sql, django

I wrote this code for Chartit but I want an SLQ raw query:

```
def weather_chart_day_view(request):
    patient=request.POST['patient']
    id=patient_complete.objects.get(complite=patient).id
    date=request.POST['date']
    date1=request.POST['date1']
    fsuivie_horraire.objects.raw('SELECT  id,date_sh, avg(temp)as 
temp, patient FROM 
    public.fsuivie_horraire where  patient='+str(id)+' and date_sh > 
'+date+' group  by id,date_sh, patient;')} '''
```

I got this error :

> ProgrammingError at /graphe/temperature_jour/
>   operator does not exist: date > integer
>   LINE 1: ...lic.fsuivie_horraire where  patient=3 and date_sh > 2020-03-...

Comment: Please don't. You expose your database to possibly SQL injection. Exactly what do you want to do? Usually it is better to write an ORM query. Please share your model and explain *what* you aim to do.

Comment: Imagine that a user writes `'' OR 1=1` in the `'date'` POST parameter, than the database can get exposed. Or even worse `''; DROP DATABASE ...`, then it can drop all your data.

Comment: i want calculate sum of temperature  from id of patient for one or two months or year it depends in date between two values

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is mentioning, you are susceptible to SQL injection attacks here. However, despite that. I am going to guess that the problem is your `date` field. Assuming that it is a `DateTime` field it will need to be quoted.

Try changing query to

```
'SELECT id, date_sh, avg(temp) as temp, patient FROM 
    public.fsuivie_horraire where  patient='+str(id)+' and date_sh > \''+date+'\' 
    group by id, date_sh, patient;'
```